# Need to integrate Wix projects into daily builds

Tags: c#, msbuild, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I need to integrate Wix projects into daily builds. I have followed following [Link](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html) and have set

```
<WixToolPath>E:\where\cplusplus\thirdparty\windows\wix\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\</WixToolPath>
<WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">E:\where\cplusplus\thirdparty\windows\wix\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
<WixTasksPath>E:\where\cplusplus\thirdparty\windows\wix\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
```

When I build my project after having set above properties I see my project picking up `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK` instead I want it to be picked from `E:\where\cplusplus\thirdparty\windows\wix\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK`.
see output log:

```
Searching for custom action entry points in CustomAction.dll
  Loaded dependent assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll
  Install=CustomAction!CustomAction.CustomActions.Install
  UnInstall=CustomAction!CustomAction.CustomActions.UnInstall
```

Searching for an embedded UI class in CustomAction.dll
  Modifying SfxCA.dll stub

What additional property do I have to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit difficult to see from information you have provided what is referencing that DLL. Maybe having your whole wixproj would be easier.

However, check all your projects, most likely one of the projects has a reference to Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll.
In my case i had a reference:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ce35f76fcda82bad, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>$(WIX)bin\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

In this case change the property $(WIX) to your path. Preferably create a Property with the path like you did with `<WixToolPath>` for example `<WixSDKPath>E:\where\cplusplus\thirdparty\windows\wix\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK\</WixSDKPath>` then in HintPath use that property:
`<HintPath>$(WixSDKPath)\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll</HintPath>`

Also you forgot to add `<WixTargetsPath>`